# How to center a div with css-grids?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

You can see my project here: https://jsfiddle.net/alphatier/byfvpq8h/2/

```css
.i {
  grid-area: i;
}

.t {
  grid-area: t;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-areas: "i t";
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media(min-width: 350px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  }
  .box {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-areas: "i" "t";
    text-align: center;
  }
  .t {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 475px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 590px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 705px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 820px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 935px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACr+O9WAAACt0lEQVR4nO3SwZKjUAxDUf7/p6cXmVVXaISeZCC5rnq7YMs+2bZt+3fF+12tvu/K+aaV13yggQYaaKAJaK1qoE1lVfJOZgFNyAoaaMtZQBOyPg4tdczEnIUlT/VNobWygAYaaBNZQAMNtIkst0FrlYMP2oklGwUaaLu/UfuAJhRoRbTUoZz8rSygiYdy8reygCYeysnfygKaeCgnfyvLZWipasx52h/IKdDELKDtDG/0BK08vNETtPLwRs+vRZt6rUNdhTb8QAMNNNBAe/PebnXTUkCOvnEB7lT3SnNQoL3qXmkOCrRX3SvNQYH2qi11iLs+8yiRvok/y84DzdnP6RO8I2jOfk6f4B1Bc/Zz+gTvCJqzn9MneMfzjVtLnj3Cnf4Mk3860EADDbShwzwezTn2ZOCz5Rzc6avODt0WNNBA+3M2aGa2o984fdXZI2jOcZ2ALTR11uqB3buYDzTQxAUS37gFGmhyftAW6uPRWkdozUlkc7K0CjTQDhuDFijQvhntKgCnrzt7KouZHzTQQDuVxcwPGmigncpi5p8BaBzFraksibvsPNBAA02eA9qJ+jg0J0xiIWfp1KGcvE7f4DegOXlBAw000EoLJY55JchViP+/Aw000EBbnXtlftDMuVfmr6FJWw3UFLSbJdFHmQNaMEuijzIHtGCWRB9lDmjBLIk+yhwJLXWs1eO2DtXKIh63tQ9oThbQxEMtLAkaaDdDa5VzqMZxU7MTOzs9QFuYndjZ6QHawuzEzk4P0BZmJ3Z2eoC2MDuxs9NDQlMWUsI9HS3xlBJ7gQYaaKCB9nA0Z45zvBaIUqCBBhpoQ3NAK6I53yizmwc+Kud2oIm/aRVooIE2UaCBpqO1Fmj0dP9UiT9UYi5ooK0XaKC97fm1aFMvuMDy7AaI0tf5BjTQQAMNNNA+Ce0HIleXZZmQRJwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
</div>
```

It displays qr codes and it displays a text for each qr code.

If the screen size is < `350px`, the layout is smartphone-optimized and I'm glad with that. But if the screen size is >= `350p`x, I don't know **how to center it.**

Let's pick a screen size between `350px` and `475px`, **for example, 460px**. Then, you can see 3 qr codes with their text in a row. But on the right side, there is a lot of space. How can I center those 3 qr codes?

The code

```
margin: auto
```

didn't work for me because the width of `div.grid` is maximum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `justify-content: center` to class `.grid` 
https://jsfiddle.net/byfvpq8h/3/

```css
.i {
  grid-area: i;
}

.t {
  grid-area: t;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-areas: "i t";
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media(min-width: 350px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  }
  .box {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-areas: "i" "t";
    text-align: center;
  }
  .t {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 475px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 590px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 705px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 820px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 100px);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 935px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACr+O9WAAACt0lEQVR4nO3SwZKjUAxDUf7/p6cXmVVXaISeZCC5rnq7YMs+2bZt+3fF+12tvu/K+aaV13yggQYaaKAJaK1qoE1lVfJOZgFNyAoaaMtZQBOyPg4tdczEnIUlT/VNobWygAYaaBNZQAMNtIkst0FrlYMP2oklGwUaaLu/UfuAJhRoRbTUoZz8rSygiYdy8reygCYeysnfygKaeCgnfyvLZWipasx52h/IKdDELKDtDG/0BK08vNETtPLwRs+vRZt6rUNdhTb8QAMNNNBAe/PebnXTUkCOvnEB7lT3SnNQoL3qXmkOCrRX3SvNQYH2qi11iLs+8yiRvok/y84DzdnP6RO8I2jOfk6f4B1Bc/Zz+gTvCJqzn9MneMfzjVtLnj3Cnf4Mk3860EADDbShwzwezTn2ZOCz5Rzc6avODt0WNNBA+3M2aGa2o984fdXZI2jOcZ2ALTR11uqB3buYDzTQxAUS37gFGmhyftAW6uPRWkdozUlkc7K0CjTQDhuDFijQvhntKgCnrzt7KouZHzTQQDuVxcwPGmigncpi5p8BaBzFraksibvsPNBAA02eA9qJ+jg0J0xiIWfp1KGcvE7f4DegOXlBAw000EoLJY55JchViP+/Aw000EBbnXtlftDMuVfmr6FJWw3UFLSbJdFHmQNaMEuijzIHtGCWRB9lDmjBLIk+yhwJLXWs1eO2DtXKIh63tQ9oThbQxEMtLAkaaDdDa5VzqMZxU7MTOzs9QFuYndjZ6QHawuzEzk4P0BZmJ3Z2eoC2MDuxs9NDQlMWUsI9HS3xlBJ7gQYaaKCB9nA0Z45zvBaIUqCBBhpoQ3NAK6I53yizmwc+Kud2oIm/aRVooIE2UaCBpqO1Fmj0dP9UiT9UYi5ooK0XaKC97fm1aFMvuMDy7AaI0tf5BjTQQAMNNNA+Ce0HIleXZZmQRJwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAG0AAABtCAYAAACr+O9WAAACt0lEQVR4nO3SwZKjUAxDUf7/p6cXmVVXaISeZCC5rnq7YMs+2bZt+3fF+12tvu/K+aaV13yggQYaaKAJaK1qoE1lVfJOZgFNyAoaaMtZQBOyPg4tdczEnIUlT/VNobWygAYaaBNZQAMNtIkst0FrlYMP2oklGwUaaLu/UfuAJhRoRbTUoZz8rSygiYdy8reygCYeysnfygKaeCgnfyvLZWipasx52h/IKdDELKDtDG/0BK08vNETtPLwRs+vRZt6rUNdhTb8QAMNNNBAe/PebnXTUkCOvnEB7lT3SnNQoL3qXmkOCrRX3SvNQYH2qi11iLs+8yiRvok/y84DzdnP6RO8I2jOfk6f4B1Bc/Zz+gTvCJqzn9MneMfzjVtLnj3Cnf4Mk3860EADDbShwzwezTn2ZOCz5Rzc6avODt0WNNBA+3M2aGa2o984fdXZI2jOcZ2ALTR11uqB3buYDzTQxAUS37gFGmhyftAW6uPRWkdozUlkc7K0CjTQDhuDFijQvhntKgCnrzt7KouZHzTQQDuVxcwPGmigncpi5p8BaBzFraksibvsPNBAA02eA9qJ+jg0J0xiIWfp1KGcvE7f4DegOXlBAw000EoLJY55JchViP+/Aw000EBbnXtlftDMuVfmr6FJWw3UFLSbJdFHmQNaMEuijzIHtGCWRB9lDmjBLIk+yhwJLXWs1eO2DtXKIh63tQ9oThbQxEMtLAkaaDdDa5VzqMZxU7MTOzs9QFuYndjZ6QHawuzEzk4P0BZmJ3Z2eoC2MDuxs9NDQlMWUsI9HS3xlBJ7gQYaaKCB9nA0Z45zvBaIUqCBBhpoQ3NAK6I53yizmwc+Kud2oIm/aRVooIE2UaCBpqO1Fmj0dP9UiT9UYi5ooK0XaKC97fm1aFMvuMDy7AaI0tf5BjTQQAMNNNA+Ce0HIleXZZmQRJwAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img class="i" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    /><span class="t">text about the qrcode</span></div>
</div>
```

Refer to this for more CSS grid tips 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**:

This is what you were starting off with.
[image: original code]

Using `justify-content: center` gives you this.
[image: justify content center]

Following the suggestion by @abhishek-soni 
Using `justify-content: space-around` gives you this.
[image]

Pick whichever is more suitable for your needs @Alpha

Answer (score 3):

I find the easiest technique in centering a div is using a grid:

html:

```html
<article class="grid-parent">
    
    <div>"I'm a div!</div>
    
</article>
```

```css
.grid-parent {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

The place-items property in CSS is shorthand for the align-items and justify-items properties, combining them into a single declaration.

For further insight: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/place-items/

Comment: Does this actually work? Running the snippet doesn't really show what's happening here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Done!
The property `justify-content` tells the grid how to align the items in the case of extra space. It has multiple valid values, like `start`(left), `end`(right) and `center`(center). The one you want is `center`.

This property is applied on the grid element

Here's the pen.
[Link to pen](https://jsfiddle.net/wxahwhj9/)

Also, here's some docs. [Link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)

---

But, in my opinion, doing `justify-content: space-around;` looks nicer for your case. Up to you of course, just stating my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 
`place-items: center;`
That will combine 2 properties of the parent container as one.
And use The `justify-content:center;` and `align-items center` as well.